# Installing opencv for Python

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I have both Python 3.7 and 2.7 installed currently, and have a simple image processing script that calls for opencv. However, I keep getting the "module not found" error. I've tried using pip install, pip3 install, and installing the Windows executable from the opencv website, none of which have fixed the problem. The script won't run from either 3.7 or 2.7! I'm currently trying to use Visual Studio Code on a Windows 10 Surface computer.

Other threads seem to suggest that I need to update the Python registry/pointer or something to reflect the actual install location, but I can't seem to find how to do this. Or can I simply copy/paste the directory or files into Python directly? (Python 3.7 is preferred, or for both if possible!)

Edit: After uninstalling and reinstalling both Python 2.7 and 3.7, I think I figured out what the problem was! I was still having issues upon reinstall, so I tried rolling back a version to 3.6. During this installation, I noticed that even pip wasn't working anymore. It was at this point I realized that somehow my installation of Python was done with administrative privileges by default. Even though my account is the only one running on my personal computer, I still had to install pip with elevated privileges to get it to work. Now it seems like OpenCV and other modules are working!

Comment: I would recommend searching online for how to set up virtual environments for Python :)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'll do that, thanks!